# Reducing self-selection bias by controlling for motivation to fill in the survey

Tags: measurement, reference-request, methodology, motivation, selection-recruitment

The [self-selection bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-selection_bias) refers to the overrepresentation of people willing to participate in research among studies' participants. The bias could be particularly relevant in surveys relevant to motivation which rely on representative samples, for ex. those mapping prevalence of certain mental health problems.

I was surprised to be unable to find any studies which would use a variable such as "I was very motivated to fill in this survey" to measure the potential effect of the bias. Therefore, I'm looking for recommendations for any articles that tried to evaluate how effective might a similar approach be to increase the certainty the conclusions apply to the population in question.